# C++: error 2665 None of the 4 overloads could convert all argument types

Tags: c++

Ok, so I am having an error I don't know how to fix it.

The code

```
        CAI_Hint *pHint = CAI_HintManager::FindHint( this, GetEnemy()->GetAbsOrigin(), &hint );

        if ( pHint == NULL )
        {
            TaskFail( "Unable to find vantage point!\n" );
            break;
        }
```

The IntelliSense:

```
no instance of overloaded function "CAI_HintManager::FindHint" matches the argument list
argument types are: (CNPC_Assassin *, const Vector, CHintCriteria *)
```

The compiler error:

```
error C2665: 'CAI_HintManager::FindHint' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

Here is the function declaration's for FindHint

```
    static CAI_Hint     *FindHint( CAI_BaseNPC *pNPC, const Vector &position, const CHintCriteria &hintCriteria );
    static CAI_Hint     *FindHint( CAI_BaseNPC *pNPC, const CHintCriteria &hintCriteria );
    static CAI_Hint     *FindHint( const Vector &position, const CHintCriteria &hintCriteria );
    static CAI_Hint     *FindHint( CAI_BaseNPC *pNPC, Hint_e nHintType, int nFlags, float flMaxDist, const Vector *pMaxDistFrom = NULL );
```

I have tried to look for ways to fix it but were not suitable
could it be that I have to change to be relative to the declarations? I don't know.
And Mircosoft documentation is a little bit vague.

Comment: What is `CAI_BaseNPC`? What is `Vector`? What is `CHintCriteria`? What is `CAI_HintManager`? What is `GetEnemy`? Please strip this down to a self-contained 50-line example and create a [mcve] so that the question can be correctly answered.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that the ampersand `&` in `&hint` does not belong

Comment: drop the & in `&hint`, it wants a reference for the third argument, not a pointer